# How to resolve attribute values in angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive which picks up the template file as well as the controller based on the value of one of the attributes.

Here's my directive so far:

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
            return "/" + attrs.targetpath + ".html";
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: '@',
        name: 'targetpath'
    };
});
```

And I use it like...

```
<my-dir targetpath='path'></my-dir>
```

I have this scope variable which stores the path like so

```
$scope.path = 'someWhere';
```

The problem is that the directive treats the `targetpath` attribute as a string and not as a scope variable.

So, it looks for `/path.html` with `path` controller, instead of `/someWhere.html` with `someWhere` controller

[Plunk's over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICF4fTxEBqK3bhHcTgOL?p=preview)

Comment: what is `name: 'targetpath',` there?? comment it and see if you desired results ??

Comment: No luck, getting the same error as before `Argument 'path' is not a function, got undefined`. Should I permanently remove this line anyway?

Comment: can you create the fiddle

Comment: Alright, [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICF4fTxEBqK3bhHcTgOL?p=preview) the plunk (couldn't create multiple html files in fiddle)